# What is the min-max argument in mathematics?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, proof-explanation

In the proof of a theorem the author says that he would prove a special case using the min-max argument. After reading the proof I could not infer what the min-max argument actually does. Could someone throw some light on what it could actually mean. I am attaching a screen shot of the proof[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling "minimax stochastic analysis"?

Comment: @JimmyR. I just added it

Comment: @rogerl I tried min-max but not stochastic analysis min-max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimax argument is the following. For any $μ\ge 0$

$$E\left[{M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2}}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}\le\inf_{μ>0}{\left\{E\left[\sup_{t\ge0}{(M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2})}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}\right\}}$$

The expression on the LHS is bounded by a min-max (inf-sup) expression on the RHS. Specifically, the proof above consists of the following steps:

1. Obvious equation: $E[M_t^*]=E\left[{M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2}}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}$ for any $μ\ge 0$.
2. Taking the $\sup$ over $t$ on the RHS turns the $=$ to $\le$ for the LHS
   $$E[M_t^*]\le E\left[\sup_{t\ge0}{\left(M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2}\right)}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}$$
3. Some manipulation on $M_t^*$ (where $B^*_t$ is introduced) and equation $(13.5)$ is reached. This is equivalent to the equation in Step 2. here.
4. Some more manipulation on the RHS (scaling property etc.). Steps 3. and 4. are irrelevant to the min-max argument.
5. **The min-max argument**: Since $(13.5)$ (modulo the manipulation) holds for any $μ\ge 0$ then is holds also for the $\inf_{μ>0}$.

Step 5. leads to the penultimate equation which can be written as (if we ignore the manipulation and in order to highlight the inf-sup expression on the RHS): \begin{align}E[M_L^*]&\le\inf_{μ>0}{\left\{E\left[\sup_{t\ge0}{(B^*_t-μt^{r/2})}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}\right\}}\\[0.2cm]\iff E\left[{M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2}}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}&\le\inf_{μ>0}{\left\{E\left[\sup_{t\ge0}{(M^*_t-μ\langle M\rangle_L^{r/2})}\right]+μE[\langle M\rangle]_L^{r/2}\right\}}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much . I have one further question. I can't see why $C_r $ is an explicit function of $\varphi_r(1)$ I mean $\|\langle M \rangle_L^{1/2}\|_r=E[\langle M \rangle_L^{r/2}]^{1/r}$ but there is no way(that i can see) that we can write the RHS as $C_r \|\langle M \rangle_L^{1/2}\|_r$

Comment: Ok, you know what explicit function means, so I assume that the question is which is it. With a slight risk, I will say the following: Let $μ^*$ give the inf (so here is the risk, because such a $μ^*$ may not exist, but let's say for ease that it exists) then you can write the RHS as $μ^{*1/1-r}φ_r(1)+μ^*\|M\|=μ^{*1/1-r}(φ_r(1)/\|M\|+μ^*)\|M\|=C_r\|M\|$. Do you think this is it? Or even better you can replace the $=$ with $\le$ and have some more leeway (instead of bringing $\|M\|$ in the denominator)

Comment: Thank you, my confusion was how could we get an explicit expression with the infimum which might not be attained for any $\mu$